# Vimeo embed iframe not visible in IE11

Tags: html, css, iframe, vimeo, internet-explorer-11

I append iframes containing vimeo embed code to a website, hide the iframes and display the first one when it is loaded.

Works in: Chrome, Safari, Firefox, IE 9-11 on Win7 and IE10 on Win8
Does not work in: Internet Explorer 11 on Win8.1

It shows me a black box, I can press the invisible play button and there's sound, but there's nothing to see. 
Funny thing: by resizing the browser window the iframe magically appears and video playback works.

Comment: I have try it and it works... Tested on browserstack.com / IE 11 / WIN 8.1

Comment: Thanks for trying. It works like 1 out of 5 times but when you navigate a little it's all messed up again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some oddities relating to loading players from a `display: none` state. For now you could try a workaround I've used a few times and that is firing a fake resize event when you want the player to load, something like this:

`window.dispatchEvent(new Event( 'resize', true, true ));`

(Sorry for any typos, I'm on my phone.)

Comment: Thank you! The fake resize didn't work but knowing the `display: none` was causing the issue I solved the problem by working with opacity and z-index instead.